# Eaton Circuit Breaker small LED on but not tripped

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

Why are the red LED lights next to Test button solid red picture[image] as follow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about the use of devices. It's a better fit on the Home Improvement site.

Comment: *Solid* (just on) does not seem to be listed. Various numbers of *blinks* are supposed to indicate why it tripped the last time. I'd try shutting them off, waiting a minute, and switching them on to see if the problem persists - and/or using the test button to test functioning. Detailed documentation appears to be annoyingly hard to find.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Disregard.

Long answer: Disregard until you are trying to figure out why the blazes your breaker is tripping.  (i.e. overload vs GFCI vs AFCI).

The latest generations of Eaton AFCI/GFCI breakers give very robust data on what caused the last trip, and more importantly, *they store that data indefinitely*, the data doesn't auto-clear just when you need to see it.  Rather handy, eh?

And *it **just** displays the data*... all the time.  Competitor breakers's so-called "Time Saver diagnostics" make you stand on one foot and touch your nose three times... *this is better*.

So, once you experience a breaker trip, that red light will "tap out" the reason for the previous trip.  Since it hasn't had a trip, it's in an indeterminate state, and can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The [installation manual](https://images.thdstatic.com/catalog/pdfImages/db/db9c58e8-b76f-428b-a4e1-ea04348e36ed.pdf) does not say anything about a solid red light. Since LEDs last a ridiculously long time, it could well be that they decided at some point to have the LED solid as a power indicator. Note that [based on Eaton's color coding](http://trcsupport.eaton.com/Residential-Distribution/Loadcenters-Resi-Breakers/1010506601/What-is-the-color-scheme-of-the-AFCI-GFCI-and-AFGF-residential-breakers.htm) you have a red light on the Blue == AFCI/GFCI breakers and *not* on the Green == AFCI breakers.

A way to check this out is to use a [3-light magic 8-ball tester with GFCI tester](https://amzn.to/3haP9AT):

[image: GFCI Tester]

and see if it activates the breaker correctly. If it works correctly, you should get a 5-blink code. The code displays for 30 iterations after a power cycle and then goes back to "normal". If after that it goes back to solid red (and the circuit has power and functions properly) then the answer is "solid red = OK". If after that it goes to "no light" (and the circuit has power and functions properly) then it may make sense to contact Eaton.

Comment: A 3 wire tester may not work in all cases. In the case where it is a 2 wire system without a ground the tester won’t trip the GFCI and may show open ground but may have been totally legal when installed, the receptacles in this case are supposed to be marked GFCI protected no equipment ground. Unfortunately breakers don’t come with the stickers and unless inspected this is not caught.

Comment: Good point. I'm optimistic that this is a properly grounded system, but if this is not the original panel then anything is possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple questions with similar problems, the manufacturers say they cannot say what the problem is and that it is a variation in manufacturing but the device is protecting the circuit as advertised.

Problems like this can occur with new device types.
At this time the devices are considered safe and preforming the safety protection they are designed for.

If you are uncomfortable with this explanation send this photo to the MFG with the question and you may get luck with replacements.

More likely you will get a form letter with the above information as this is happening to multiple brands.